cant load .marko file in Es modules
am trying to load Marko templates in an Express.js project using Node.js version 20 with type: "module". I was expecting the Marko templates to load correctly, but I'm encountering issues.
server.js
enter image description here
and my packages json look like this
enter image description here
can anyone help to load marko pages in es module?
